# Error : Comparing Two tables in Oracle PLSQl Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below PLSQL Program to compare two tables using the Minus Operator and storing in a TYPE of VARCHAR. The procedure compiles successfully, but when executing I get the error mentioned below.All the types in the table is varchar2

```
create or replace procedure compare_tables(t1 in varchar2, t2 in varchar2)
is
    v_qry          varchar2(10000);
    TYPE T_MY_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
    v_cmp_cols     T_MY_LIST;  -- list of distinct
begin
            FOR i in 1..1000
            loop

                v_qry:= 'SELECT JOB_NAME' ||','|| 'TYPE_OF_BATCH FROM ' 
                      || t1
                      || ' MINUS SELECT JOB_NAME' ||','|| 'TYPE_OF_BATCH FROM '
                      || t2 ;

                DBMS_Output.PUT_LINE (v_qry);
                execute immediate v_qry bulk collect into v_cmp_cols;
                FOR j in 1..v_cmp_cols.count loop
                 DBMS_Output.PUT_LINE (v_cmp_cols(j));
               end loop;
            end loop;    

end compare_tables;

begin
    compare_tables('a','b');
end;

enter Error report -

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
ORA-06512: at "STSC.COMPARE_TABLES", line 20
ORA-06512: at line 2
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:code here
```

Comment: i am not that experienced in oralce user-defined but if you remove `TYPE_OF_BATCH` youll not have the error right ? can you try that please.

Comment: please add `a` and `b` tables DDLs

Comment: Why are you running the same query 1000 times? Are you planning on limiting the bulk-collect to restrict the collection size, and etch in chunks in a loop? This isn't how you would do that, but it's all I can think of...

Answer (score 4):

Your query is selecting two columns, but you're trying to bulk-collect into a single collection of a scalar data type.

Either declare two collections variables:

```
TYPE T_MY_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
v_cmp_job_name      T_MY_LIST;
v_cmp_type_of_batch T_MY_LIST;
```

and then use both:

```
            execute immediate v_qry bulk collect into v_cmp_job_name, v_cmp_type_of_batch;
            FOR j in 1..v_cmp_job_name.count loop
             DBMS_Output.PUT_LINE (v_cmp_job_name(j) ||','|| v_cmp_type_of_batch(j));
           end loop;
```

Or declare a record type and a collection of those:

```
TYPE T_MY_REC IS RECORD (
    job_name varchar2(100),
    type_of_batch varchar2(100)
);
TYPE T_MY_LIST IS TABLE OF T_MY_REC;
v_cmp_cols T_MY_LIST;
```

and use one collection, referring to its fields:

```
            execute immediate v_qry bulk collect into v_cmp_cols;
            FOR j in 1..v_cmp_cols.count loop
             DBMS_Output.PUT_LINE (v_cmp_cols(j).job_name
                           ||','|| v_cmp_cols(j).type_of_batch);
           end loop;
```